# Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11 when trying to build

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm feeling lost with this error, can somebody help?

**My Code:**

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore
import SDWebImage
import VBFPopFlatButton
import Parse
import Koloda


class DiscoverViewController: UIViewController, KolodaViewDataSource, KolodaViewDelegate {

    // MARK: Variables

    var response = ""

    var tvShows = [TVShow]()

    var numberOfCards: UInt = 20

    // MARK: Outlets

    @IBOutlet weak var menuButton: VBFPopFlatButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var showPoster: KolodaView!

    // MARK: Actions

    @IBAction func openMenu(sender: AnyObject) {
        let menu = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MenuView") as!
        MenuViewController

        let mainNavContr = self.navigationController as! MainNavigationController

        menu.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Custom

        menu.delegate = mainNavContr

        presentViewController(menu, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }


    @IBAction func notLiked(sender: AnyObject) {
        showPoster.swipe(SwipeResultDirection.Left)
    }


    @IBAction func liked(sender: AnyObject) {

        let show = self.tvShows[showPoster.currentCardNumber]

        UserLikedShows.userLikedShow(show, response: { (response) -> Void in
            switch response {
            case .Failure(let error):
                print(error)
            case .Success(_):
                print("like success")
            }
        })

        showPoster.swipe(SwipeResultDirection.Right)
    }


    // MARK: iOS

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        showPoster.layer.cornerRadius = 10

        showPoster.dataSource = self
        showPoster.delegate = self

        TVShow.getPopular { (response) -> () in
            switch response {

            case .Success(let shows) :
                self.tvShows = shows
                self.showPoster.reloadData()

            case .Failure(let error) :
                print(error, terminator: "")
            }
        }

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        styleMenu()
    }

    // MARK: Go to Recommendations

    func changeController() {

        let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

        userDefaults.setBool(true, forKey: didFinishRecommendationsKey)

        let mainNavContr = self.navigationController as! MainNavigationController
        let recommendationsViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Recommendations") 
        mainNavContr.setViewControllers([recommendationsViewController], animated: false)

    }

    // MARK: Menu

    func styleMenu() {

        menuButton.currentButtonType = FlatButtonType.buttonMenuType
        menuButton.currentButtonStyle = FlatButtonStyle.buttonPlainStyle
        menuButton.lineThickness = 2
        menuButton.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }

    // MARK: Koloda
    func kolodaNumberOfCards(koloda: KolodaView) -> UInt {
        return numberOfCards
    }

    func kolodaViewForCardAtIndex(koloda: KolodaView, index: UInt) -> UIView {

        let bg = UIImageView()

        bg.frame = showPoster.bounds

        if tvShows.count > 0 {
            bg.sd_setImageWithURL(tvShows[Int(index)].posterURL, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "nopreview"))

            view.insertSubview(bg, aboveSubview: showPoster)

            return bg
        } else {
            return UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "nopreview"))
        }

    }

    func kolodaViewForCardOverlayAtIndex(koloda: KolodaView, index: UInt) -> OverlayView? {
        return nil
    }

    func kolodaDidSwipedCardAtIndex(koloda: KolodaView, index: UInt, direction: SwipeResultDirection) {

        if direction == SwipeResultDirection.Right {

            let show = self.tvShows[Int(index)]

            UserLikedShows.userLikedShow(show, response: { (response) -> Void in
                switch response {
                case .Failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                case .Success(_):
                    print("like success")
                }
            })
        }

    }

    func kolodaDidRunOutOfCards(koloda: KolodaView) {
        changeController()
    }

    func kolodaShouldApplyAppearAnimation(koloda: KolodaView) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func kolodaShouldMoveBackgroundCard(koloda: KolodaView) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func kolodaShouldTransparentizeNextCard(koloda: KolodaView) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

}
```

**Compiler error message:**

```
CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/DiscoverViewController.swift
    cd /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/DescriptionViewController.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/LoginViewController.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/UserSavedShows.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/MySeriesViewController.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/SelectedEpisodeViewController.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/Mood.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/MainNavigationController.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/AvatarView.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/SeasonsCollectionViewCell.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/TVShow.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/User.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/SearchTableViewCell.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/EpisodesCollectionViewCell.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/SearchResultsTableViewController.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/SeriesPosterCollectionViewCell.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/AiringTodayViewController.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/RecommendationViewController.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/Genre.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/UserLikedShows.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/AppDelegate.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/Session.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/MenuViewController.swift -primary-file /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/DiscoverViewController.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/DeleteAlertViewController.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/SettingsViewController.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/AiringTodayTableViewCell.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/SeasonsViewController.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/Constants.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/UserWatchedEpisodes.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/EpisodesViewController.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/MoodGenre.swift -target x86_64-apple-ios8.0 -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk -I /Users/bmbrina/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Surfies-dixlbskdjnkdcdcuwupxgblgwhju/Build/Products/Debug-Staging-iphonesimulator -F /Users/bmbrina/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Surfies-dixlbskdjnkdcdcuwupxgblgwhju/Build/Products/Debug-Staging-iphonesimulator -enable-testing -g -import-objc-header /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/Surfies-Bridging-Header.h -module-cache-path /Users/bmbrina/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -D Debug -D Staging -D COCOAPODS -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -I/Users/bmbrina/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Surfies-dixlbskdjnkdcdcuwupxgblgwhju/Build/Intermediates/Surfies.build/Debug-Staging-iphonesimulator/Surfies.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/bmbrina/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Surfies-dixlbskdjnkdcdcuwupxgblgwhju/Build/Intermediates/Surfies.build/Debug-Staging-iphonesimulator/Surfies.build/Surfies-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/bmbrina/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Surfies-dixlbskdjnkdcdcuwupxgblgwhju/Build/Intermediates/Surfies.build/Debug-Staging-iphonesimulator/Surfies.build/Surfies-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/bmbrina/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Surfies-dixlbskdjnkdcdcuwupxgblgwhju/Build/Intermediates/Surfies.build/Debug-Staging-iphonesimulator/Surfies.build/Surfies-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/bmbrina/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Surfies-dixlbskdjnkdcdcuwupxgblgwhju/Build/Intermediates/Surfies.build/all-product-headers.yaml -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/bmbrina/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Surfies-dixlbskdjnkdcdcuwupxgblgwhju/Build/Intermediates/Surfies.build/Debug-Staging-iphonesimulator/Surfies.build/Surfies-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/bmbrina/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Surfies-dixlbskdjnkdcdcuwupxgblgwhju/Build/Products/Debug-Staging-iphonesimulator/include -Xcc -I/Users/bmbrina/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Surfies-dixlbskdjnkdcdcuwupxgblgwhju/Build/Intermediates/Surfies.build/Debug-Staging-iphonesimulator/Surfies.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -Xcc -I/Users/bmbrina/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Surfies-dixlbskdjnkdcdcuwupxgblgwhju/Build/Intermediates/Surfies.build/Debug-Staging-iphonesimulator/Surfies.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DSTAGING=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS=1 -Xcc -working-directory/Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies -emit-module-doc-path /Users/bmbrina/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Surfies-dixlbskdjnkdcdcuwupxgblgwhju/Build/Intermediates/Surfies.build/Debug-Staging-iphonesimulator/Surfies.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DiscoverViewController~partial.swiftdoc -Onone -module-name Surfies -emit-module-path /Users/bmbrina/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Surfies-dixlbskdjnkdcdcuwupxgblgwhju/Build/Intermediates/Surfies.build/Debug-Staging-iphonesimulator/Surfies.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DiscoverViewController~partial.swiftmodule -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/bmbrina/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Surfies-dixlbskdjnkdcdcuwupxgblgwhju/Build/Intermediates/Surfies.build/Debug-Staging-iphonesimulator/Surfies.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DiscoverViewController.dia -emit-dependencies-path /Users/bmbrina/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Surfies-dixlbskdjnkdcdcuwupxgblgwhju/Build/Intermediates/Surfies.build/Debug-Staging-iphonesimulator/Surfies.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DiscoverViewController.d -emit-reference-dependencies-path /Users/bmbrina/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Surfies-dixlbskdjnkdcdcuwupxgblgwhju/Build/Intermediates/Surfies.build/Debug-Staging-iphonesimulator/Surfies.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DiscoverViewController.swiftdeps -o /Users/bmbrina/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Surfies-dixlbskdjnkdcdcuwupxgblgwhju/Build/Intermediates/Surfies.build/Debug-Staging-iphonesimulator/Surfies.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DiscoverViewController.o

0  swift                    0x0000000111a83fbb llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(__sFILE*) + 43
1  swift                    0x0000000111a846fb SignalHandler(int) + 379
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff8ea19eaa _sigtramp + 26
3  swift                    0x0000000110206e58 swift::NominalTypeDecl::prepareExtensions() + 40
4  swift                    0x000000010fd4a707 swift::SILWitnessVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::SILGenConformance>::visitProtocolDecl(swift::ProtocolDecl*) + 999
5  swift                    0x000000010fd47ee5 swift::Lowering::SILGenModule::getWitnessTable(swift::ProtocolConformance*) + 277
6  swift                    0x000000010fd975b0 (anonymous namespace)::SILGenType::emitType() + 1264
7  swift                    0x000000010fd9704e swift::Lowering::SILGenModule::visitNominalTypeDecl(swift::NominalTypeDecl*) + 30
8  swift                    0x000000010fd1fbdb swift::Lowering::SILGenModule::emitSourceFile(swift::SourceFile*, unsigned int) + 779
9  swift                    0x000000010fd20790 swift::SILModule::constructSIL(swift::ModuleDecl*, swift::SILOptions&, swift::FileUnit*, llvm::Optional<unsigned int>, bool, bool) + 928
10 swift                    0x000000010fd20b3d swift::performSILGeneration(swift::FileUnit&, swift::SILOptions&, llvm::Optional<unsigned int>, bool) + 109
11 swift                    0x000000010fb74992 performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&) + 11442
12 swift                    0x000000010fb71ad3 frontend_main(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*) + 2691
13 swift                    0x000000010fb6e154 main + 2324
14 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff98e445ad start + 1
15 libdyld.dylib            0x0000000000000068 start + 1729870524
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/DescriptionViewController.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/LoginViewController.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/UserSavedShows.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/MySeriesViewController.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/SelectedEpisodeViewController.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/Mood.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/MainNavigationController.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/AvatarView.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/SeasonsCollectionViewCell.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/TVShow.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/User.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/SearchTableViewCell.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/EpisodesCollectionViewCell.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/SearchResultsTableViewController.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/SeriesPosterCollectionViewCell.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/AiringTodayViewController.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/RecommendationViewController.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/Genre.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/UserLikedShows.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/AppDelegate.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/Session.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/MenuViewController.swift -primary-file /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/DiscoverViewController.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/DeleteAlertViewController.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/SettingsViewController.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/AiringTodayTableViewCell.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/SeasonsViewController.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/Constants.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/UserWatchedEpisodes.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/EpisodesViewController.swift /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/MoodGenre.swift -target x86_64-apple-ios8.0 -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk -I /Users/bmbrina/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Surfies-dixlbskdjnkdcdcuwupxgblgwhju/Build/Products/Debug-Staging-iphonesimulator -F /Users/bmbrina/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Surfies-dixlbskdjnkdcdcuwupxgblgwhju/Build/Products/Debug-Staging-iphonesimulator -enable-testing -g -import-objc-header /Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies/Surfies/Surfies-Bridging-Header.h -module-cache-path /Users/bmbrina/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -D Debug -D Staging -D COCOAPODS -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -I/Users/bmbrina/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Surfies-dixlbskdjnkdcdcuwupxgblgwhju/Build/Intermediates/Surfies.build/Debug-Staging-iphonesimulator/Surfies.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/bmbrina/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Surfies-dixlbskdjnkdcdcuwupxgblgwhju/Build/Intermediates/Surfies.build/Debug-Staging-iphonesimulator/Surfies.build/Surfies-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/bmbrina/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Surfies-dixlbskdjnkdcdcuwupxgblgwhju/Build/Intermediates/Surfies.build/Debug-Staging-iphonesimulator/Surfies.build/Surfies-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/bmbrina/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Surfies-dixlbskdjnkdcdcuwupxgblgwhju/Build/Intermediates/Surfies.build/Debug-Staging-iphonesimulator/Surfies.build/Surfies-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/bmbrina/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Surfies-dixlbskdjnkdcdcuwupxgblgwhju/Build/Intermediates/Surfies.build/all-product-headers.yaml -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/bmbrina/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Surfies-dixlbskdjnkdcdcuwupxgblgwhju/Build/Intermediates/Surfies.build/Debug-Staging-iphonesimulator/Surfies.build/Surfies-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/bmbrina/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Surfies-dixlbskdjnkdcdcuwupxgblgwhju/Build/Products/Debug-Staging-iphonesimulator/include -Xcc -I/Users/bmbrina/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Surfies-dixlbskdjnkdcdcuwupxgblgwhju/Build/Intermediates/Surfies.build/Debug-Staging-iphonesimulator/Surfies.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -Xcc -I/Users/bmbrina/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Surfies-dixlbskdjnkdcdcuwupxgblgwhju/Build/Intermediates/Surfies.build/Debug-Staging-iphonesimulator/Surfies.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DSTAGING=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS=1 -Xcc -working-directory/Users/bmbrina/Documents/Developer/MobileDev/Apps/Surfies -emit-module-doc-path /Users/bmbrina/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Surfies-dixlbskdjnkdcdcuwupxgblgwhju/Build/Intermediates/Surfies.build/Debug-Staging-iphonesimulator/Surfies.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DiscoverViewController~partial.swiftdoc -Onone -module-name Surfies -emit-module-path /Users/bmbrina/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Surfies-dixlbskdjnkdcdcuwupxgblgwhju/Build/Intermediates/Surfies.build/Debug-Staging-iphonesimulator/Surfies.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DiscoverViewController~partial.swiftmodule -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/bmbrina/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Surfies-dixlbskdjnkdcdcuwupxgblgwhju/Build/Intermediates/Surfies.build/Debug-Staging-iphonesimulator/Surfies.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DiscoverViewController.dia -emit-dependencies-path /Users/bmbrina/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Surfies-dixlbskdjnkdcdcuwupxgblgwhju/Build/Intermediates/Surfies.build/Debug-Staging-iphonesimulator/Surfies.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DiscoverViewController.d -emit-reference-dependencies-path /Users/bmbrina/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Surfies-dixlbskdjnkdcdcuwupxgblgwhju/Build/Intermediates/Surfies.build/Debug-Staging-iphonesimulator/Surfies.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DiscoverViewController.swiftdeps -o /Users/bmbrina/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Surfies-dixlbskdjnkdcdcuwupxgblgwhju/Build/Intermediates/Surfies.build/Debug-Staging-iphonesimulator/Surfies.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DiscoverViewController.o
```

I was getting an error with a CocoaPod called *Koloda* and I fixed it accordingly to their Github repo and when I tried to build my project the following error appears: **Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11**.

It says which class the problem is and that's the same class in which I use that pod (Koloda). I tried to erase the functions that the pod uses but the code still appears.

I've also tried cleaning the project and the dependencies but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of XCode are you using?

Comment: I'm currently using Xcode 7.2

Comment: Was the previous problem `include of non-modular header framework`?

Comment: This is a compiler bug, triggered by various uses of protocols and protocol extensions it seems. All I can suggest is to double-check all implementations of protocol functions and members have the correct type signature.

Answer (score 0):

Data Source/Delegate methods naming changed in last versions. Try to update Koloda and check naming in delegate and data source.